# Unexpected end of JSON input node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a strange erro because it only appears when I run json.parse after json.stringify.

```
const fs = require('fs');

const proj = {
  name: "karl",
  age: 22,
  alone: true
};
var json = JSON.stringify(proj);
 fs.writeFile('test.json', json, function(err, result) {
  if (err) console.log('error', err);
});
//error

const rawdata = fs.readFileSync('test.json','utf8');
let student = JSON.parse(rawdata);
console.log(student);
student.name = 'hugo';
 json = JSON.stringify(student);
fs.writeFile('test.json', json, function(err, result) {
  if (err) console.log('error', err);
});
```

when i do that i get that Error.
But if I do the two parts separately like:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const proj = {
  name: "karl",
  age: 22,
  alone: true
};
var json = JSON.stringify(proj);
 fs.writeFile('test.json', json, function(err, result) {
  if (err) console.log('error', err);
});
```

and

```
const fs = require('fs');

const rawdata = fs.readFileSync('test.json','utf8');
let student = JSON.parse(rawdata);

console.log(student);
student.name = 'hugo';
 json = JSON.stringify(student);
fs.writeFile('test.json', json, function(err, result) {
  if (err) console.log('error', err);
});
```

I get a normal output.
what is my mistake?

Comment: You need to use `writeFileSync()` so you don't try to read the file until after it's finished.

Comment: `fs.writeFile` is an [asynchronous method](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback), meaning after you call the method it will continue with the other operations, and when you try to read the `test.json` the file has not yet been written to.
Use `fs.writeFileSync` to synchronously write the file, meaning, once the code get to that point, it will wait till the file write operation is complete before processing the next line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Either use `fs.writeFileSync()` when writing the file the first time, or move the code that reads the file into the callback function.

```js
onst fs = require('fs');

const proj = {
  name: "karl",
  age: 22,
  alone: true
};
var json = JSON.stringify(proj);
fs.writeFile('test.json', json, function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('error', err);
    return;
  }
  const rawdata = fs.readFileSync('test.json', 'utf8');
  let student = JSON.parse(rawdata);
  console.log(student);
  student.name = 'hugo';
  json = JSON.stringify(student);
  fs.writeFile('test.json', json, function(err, result) {
    if (err) console.log('error', err);
  });
});
```